# Inequality with probability integrals

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, inequality

I have a problem with this inequality:

$$\int_{M}^\infty x \; dF(x)\leq M(1-F(M)) + \int_{M}^\infty (1-F)(x) \; dx $$ where $T$ is any random variable and  $$F(x)=P(T\leq x) $$ I just don't see why this necessarily holds.

Comment: I think this holds with equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
\int_M^N x F^\prime(x)dx\ .
$$
Integrating by parts
$$
\int_M^N x F^\prime(x)dx=x F(x)|_{M}^N-\int_M^N F(x)dx=N F(N)-MF(M)-\int_M^N F(x)dx
$$
$$
\leq N-M F(M)-\int_M^N F(x)dx\ ,
$$
using the fact that the CDF of a random variable is $\leq 1$. Write
$$
N =\int_{M}^N dx +M
$$
and obtain
$$
\int_M^N x F^\prime(x)dx\leq M(1-F(M))+\int_{M}^N (1-F(x))dx\ .
$$
Send $N\to\infty$ and you're done.